# yarn-berry with save selected dependencies in node_modules

Tags: node-modules, yarnpkg, yarn-v2

I want to use Gulp and ES6modules with Yarn PnP, but Gulp with ES6modules doesn't support PnP...

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'gulp' imported from /<pathToProject>/gulpfile.js
Did you mean to import gulp-npm-4.0.2-57826bdf31-c18e6c33e6.zip/node_modules/gulp/index.js?
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:864:9)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:910:18)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1005:11)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:475:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:245:18)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:79:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:78:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

If set `nodeLinker: "node-modules"` in `.yarnrc.yml` PnP will stop working...

Can I somehow specify the dependencies that need to be saved in node_modules in parallel with PnP?

Thx ^_^